# Imploding Delimiters True Position (PHP)?

Tags: php, delimiter, implode

It's a function in my class. I have no idea for imploding $newConditions with ( OR ) ( AND ).

Anybody have an idea ?

```
// @GETSSQ = Get Secured Select Query
function getSSQ($query) {
    $conDelimiters = array(' OR ',' AND '); // Condition Delimiters
    $fivaDelimiters = array('LIKE','<=>','<>','=>','<=','!=','=','<','>'); // Field & Value delimiters {Operators}
    $conditions = preg_split("/(".implode('|',$conDelimiters).")/", $query);
    $newConditions = array();
    $operator = array("operator" => null);

    foreach ($conditions as $idx => $cond) {
        $operator["index"] = strlen($cond);
        foreach ($fivaDelimiters as $sym) {
            $pos = strpos($cond,$sym);
            if ($pos === false)
                continue;
            else {
                if ($pos < $operator['index']) {
                    $operator['index'] = $pos;
                    $operator['operator'] = $sym;
                }                       
            }
        }
        // Operatör bölme işlemine devam et...
        $parts = array();
        if ($operator['operator'] === null) {
            $error = array(
                "error" => "Koşullar arası yazım hatası tespit edildi. [".$this->options['connectionType'].":".$query."]",
                "code" => "008"
            );
            $this->showError($error);
            continue;
        } else {
            $condParts = explode($operator['operator'],$cond);
            foreach ($condParts as $idx => $val) {
                $condParts[$idx] = trim($val);
            }
            $parts['field'] = $this->__getSSQ_editFields($condParts[0]);
            $parts['operator'] = $this->__getSSQ_editOperators($operator['operator']);
            $newValue = $condParts[1];
            if (count($condParts) > 2) { // If condition value has an operator character set
                unset($condParts[0]);
                $newValue = implode($operator['operator'],$condParts);
            }
            if (preg_match("/^['|\"](.*?)['|\"]$/", $newValue)) { // If value has {'} or {"} character begin & end , remove it
                $newValue = substr($newValue, 1, (strlen($newValue)-2));
            }
            $newValue = $this->__getSSQ_editValues($newValue);
            $parts['value'] = $newValue;
        } #ENDIF OPERATOR === NULL
        $newConditions[] = $parts['field'].' '.$parts['operator'].' '.$parts['value'];

    } #END FOREACH CONDITIONS
var_dump($newConditions);


}
```

For Example My Function :

```
$condition = "id=5 AND parentCategory=2 AND firstName LIKE 'B%' AND usingMobile = 'true'";
$db = new XXClass();
$db->getSSQ($condition);
```

This output =>

```
array (size=4)
   0 => string 'id = '5'' (length=8)
   1 => string 'parentCategory = '2'' (length=20)
   2 => string 'firstName LIKE 'B%'' (length=19)
   3 => string 'usingMobile = 'true'' (length=20)
```

I can reach Fields , Operators , Values with __getSSQ_editXXXXX functions

Comment: My head... it hurts. And I still don't know what you're asking. Perhaps be more clear?

Comment: That's a delicious spaghetti, but what's the question?